# sub menu like oracle site

Tags: css, submenu

i need menu like oracle menu and submenu.

http://www.oracle.com/index.html

how can i have it in my site?

Answer (score 0):

[Suckerfish dropdowns](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) are good.

And they work without JavaScript because of the `li:hover ul { display: block }` trick.

Comment: yes, yes BUT PLEASE use js or CSS3 transitions to slow down the menu disappearing or it will be just another site with an annoying menu

Comment: @Bazzz Whoops, that should be without JavaScript. BTW, they *will* work without CSS too :P

Answer (score 0):

With a right and a "View source", you can visualize the js behind [all of this](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/websites/ocomen/sitenavigation.js)!

But, what I suggest you is to do it from scratch. It's pretty easy ;)